# How to make a shadowless coloured button in Android

Tags: android, button, themes, borderless

I've been trying various ways to do this through styles but cannot get what I want. It seems I can have a coloured button with a shadow or a button with no shadow for which I can only change the text and pressed colours.

Here's what I have in my styles.xml:

```
<style name="PrimaryFlatButton"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
</style>
```

and here is what I have in my layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/pc_large_padding"
    android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:text="Search"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Which gives me a coloured button which darkens when pressed but has a shadow.

If I change the button to have a style of:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
```

Then I successfully lose the shadow but get no background colour unless the button is pressed. I presume Android's idea of "borderless" means having nothing to indicate a border at all - just plain text - rather than making a flat button.

All I want is the standard themed button, with a background colour, which changes colour when pressed, and has no shadow.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `View` and `setOnclickListener` to make it become `Button`

Comment: You can create a `selector` drawable and specify it as the `android:background` for your button. That works fine for me with borderless buttons to get a flat look.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I have decided to resort to the old school way of doing it by using a selector on the background. It still required me to set the theme to be borderless to get rid of the shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get a colored button complete with the ripple effect by creating a `selector` drawable and specifying it as the button's background. Something like this:

some_layout.xml

```
<Button
   style="@style/Theme.Flat.Button"
   <!-- Any other properties you want to set -->
   />
```

style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Flat.Button" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ripple_selector</item>
    <!-- Any other items you want to add -->
</style>
```

ripple_selector.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary">
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_enabled="false">
                <color android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />
            </item>
            <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false">
                <color android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />
            </item>
            <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
                <color android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the elevation/shadow by adding `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` to your button's XML properties.

Full button XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/pc_large_padding"
    android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:text="Search"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

You can also drop this line into your styles.xml in order to avoid adding it to every single one of your buttons

styles.xml:

```
<style name="PrimaryFlatButton"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
</style>
```

Michael's answer is also technically correct. If you would like more fine-tuned control over the styling and states of your buttons (including elevation/shadows), you can look into creating your own StateListDrawable resources for your buttons. Since you seem more interested in using the default button styling with only slight modifications, I won't go into further detail about StateListDrawables here. However, if you're interested, you can read Michael's answer as well as the StateListDrawable documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList).